# how to use a unsigned int as a normal int in a if stament

Tags: c++, if-statement, unsigned-integer

Is there any way to use two unsigned ints in an if statement a a signed int?

```
unsigned int a = 0, b = 1;
if (a - b > - 1)
    ++a;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
if (a + 1 > b) {
  ++a;
}
```

(You may need to check for and deal wrap-around, i.e. the case where `a + 1 == 0`, if your values are completely unconstrained.)

Or even (thanks to @M.M.):

```
if (a >= b) {
  ++a;
}
```

Comment: `if (a >= b)` perhaps?

Comment: @M.M: Errr.... yes :-) Forest and trees and all that. (But in my defense, my idea is a bit more general and gives hints on how negative integers can really just be defined in terms of (relations between) natural numbers.)